# Push firebase uid to multiple locations - Angularfire2 Ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I have the following which simply pushes a name into the database along with a uid.  I would like to store that uid in another location at the same time. How can I achieve this?  Im using ionic 3, angularfire2.

```
addName() {
      let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Name of user',
        message: "Enter a name for this new user",
        inputs: [
          {
            name: 'Name',
            placeholder: 'Username'
          },
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: data => {
              console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Save',
            handler: data => {
              this.users.push({
                title: data.Name,

              });

              this.posts.push({
                title: data.Name
              });
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      prompt.present();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't authenticate a user, so there's no UID (short for user-id) involved.

But if you're looking to use the same **push ID** when writing to two locations:

```
handler: data => {
  var key = this.users.push().key;
  this.users.child(key).set({
    title: data.Name,

  });

  this.posts.child(key).set({
    title: data.Name
  });
}
```

You can even combine the two `set` operations into a single update, but I'm not sure how your `users` and `posts` references are related. If both are direct children from the root, it'd be:

```
handler: data => {
  var key = this.users.push().key;
  var updates = {};
  updates["users/"+key+"/title"] = data.Name;
  updates["posts/"+key+"/title"] = data.Name;
  this.ref.update(updates);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, exactly what I needed.  Sorry about that, I was referring to the push id or unique id as you stated.  Thanks again!